# Python Pandas Parser Error -- DtypeWarning

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Everytime I import this one csv ('leads.csv') I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:1130: DtypeWarning: Columns     (11,12,13,14,17,19,20,21) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
```

I import many .csv's for this one analysis of which 'leads.csv' is only one. It's the only file with the problem. When I look at those columns in a spreadsheet application, the values are all consistent.

For example, Column 11 (which is Column K when using Excel), is a simple Boolean field and indeed, every row is populated and it's consistently populated with exactly 'FALSE' or exactly 'TRUE'. The other fields that this error message references have consistently-formatted string values with only letters and numbers. In most of these columns, there are at least some blanks.

Anyway, given all of this, I don't understand why this message keeps happening. It doesn't seem to matter much as I can use the data anyway. But here are my questions:

1) How would you go about identifying the any rows/records that are causing this error?

2) Using the low_memory=False option seems to be pretty unpopular in many of the posts I read. Do I need to declare the datatype of each field in this case? Or should I just ignore the error?